# Simple Jackson XML deserialization to Java not working

Tags: java, xml, serialization, jackson, pojo

I am hoping someone can point out what is escaping me. This is my first attempt to deserialize XML. Here is a cut-down of my problem.

Thanks,

Harold

The problem is demonstrated in Problem.java

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonCreator;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.xml.XmlMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.xml.annotation.JacksonXmlElementWrapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.xml.annotation.JacksonXmlProperty;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.xml.annotation.JacksonXmlRootElement;

public class Problem {

    public Problem() {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Problem problem = new Problem();

        problem.demonstrate();
    }


    @JacksonXmlRootElement(localName = "myroot")
    public class Myroot {
        @JacksonXmlElementWrapper(useWrapping = false)
        @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "products")
    @JsonProperty("products")
    public Products[] products;

    @JsonCreator public Myroot() {}

    public Products[] getProducts() {
    return products;
    }

    public void setProducts(Products[] products) {
        this.products = products;
    }
     }


    public class Products {
    @JsonCreator public Products() {}

    @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "foo")
    public String foo = "hi";

    public String getFoo() {
        return foo;
    }

    public void setFoo(String foo) {
        this.foo = foo;
    }
    }

    public void demonstrate()
    {
    Products products = new Products();
    Products[] productsList = new Products[1];
    productsList[0] = products;

    try {
        Myroot myrootOut= new Myroot();
        myrootOut.setProducts(productsList);

        XmlMapper xmlMapper = new XmlMapper();
        xmlMapper.writeValue(new File("J:\\stuff.xml"), myrootOut);
        Myroot migrationCompatibility = xmlMapper.readValue(new File("J:\\stuff.xml"), Myroot.class);
        System.out.println(migrationCompatibility);

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    }       

}
```

The serialization works as expected and produces the xml as expected.

```
<myroot><products><foo>hi</foo></products></myroot>
```

However the complementary call to deserialize above results in an exception. It seems it does not recognize the  tag, but I cannot not figure out why.

> com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException:
>   Unrecognized field "products" (....Problem), not marked as ignorable
>   (0 known properties: ])  at [Source: J:\stuff.xml; line: 1, column:
>   19] (through reference chain: ....Problem["products"])

Comment: Sorry, my generated XML did not come thru in my original post. "<migrationCompatibility><products><foo>hi</foo></products></migrationCompatibility>"

Comment: You can edit your post at any time. Use the `{}` button to wrap selected code or markup.

Comment: Which version of the `jackson-xml-bind` library are you using?

Comment: This works perfectly fine for me with 2.4.2.

Comment: Thanks. I am using jackson-databind-2.3.3.jar and Jackson-dataformat-xml-2.3.3.jar.

Comment: Thanks. I will try upgrading to 2.4.2.

Comment: It works with 2.3.3 as well for me.

Comment: It fails for me with 2.4.2 as well. Thanks for trying to help.

Comment: There might be something you aren't showing us. Please give a complete and reproducible example

Comment: I edited the original post to show the single cut-down java class that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: Making the root class Myroot be a static class makes it work.

Answer (score 0):

This is an issue related to inner classes. To create your `Myroot` instance, Jackson needs an enclosing `Problem` instance. It seems to attempt to do some weird deserialization. I can't explain it right now.

The simple solution is to not have inner classes. Make all your classes top-level classes (or `static` nested).